# retrieve and export histrocial transaction data

Tags: civireport, export

In order to better analyse our last mailing, i would love to view and export historical transaction data for a specific amount of Id's? Ie. show me all transaction and transaction dates connected to a specific List of CIVI id's.

Would love some advise.
Kind Regards

Comment: Do you mean all contributions for a group of contacts or do you mean something specific to mailings?

Comment: Your mailing probably had a Group (Z) as its 'target' - therefore in Adv Search (or via other tools) you could say 'show me Contribution results for contacts during date range X-Y who are in Group Z

Comment: I say 'probably' in case you sent a civimail direct from Adv Search which is a bit different as you don't create a 'group' via the UI. But in this case you should then be able to use Adv Search to filter by Mailing instead of by Group